# Can any Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) presented by Chord diagram/ Radial Network diagrams

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, chord-diagram

Given a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), can it be presented and transformed into Chord diagrams or Radial Network diagrams? Are there any cases where it cannot be transferred? Is there an algorithm that can achieve this optimally? Additionally, what are the benefits of one over the other?